# What's the best way to force a hashchange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My website uses hashchange-triggered AJAX (to make it more bookmark-friendly). The problem I am having is that when I click "submit" in a form, all the form data that is `serialize()`'d to be sent via `$.post()` gets lost. I know this because I get the "Flag 1" alert after I click submit, and various other tests (alerting, echoing, etc.) show this to be true.

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = '';
var hash = '';
newPage();
alert('Flag 1');

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == '') {
        path = window.location.pathname;
        hash = '#' + path.replace(/^\/+/, '');
    }
    data += '&func=' + hash;
    var xhr = $.post(hash, data, function(result) {
        $("maincontent").html(result);
    })
    .done(newPage);
});
// Initialize vars and handle new form elements
function newPage() {
    data = '';
    $('form').submit(function() {
        data = $(this).serialize();
        // Flag 2 - What do I do here?
    });
}
// Load ajax content on first run of document
if ($('#maincontent').html() == '')
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

What I am trying to do is *manually* fire a hashchange event while also changing the URL. The trouble is that if I just set `window.location.hash = $(this).attr('action');` then `return false;` where the "Flag 2" comment is, then I wind up getting unwanted trash in the URL, possibly due to the hashmark being encoded for a URL (...%23, etc).

I am wondering what the best way to set the hash is, and whether there is a simpler way to do what I am trying to do to begin with.

(I'm also open to comments suggesting alternate approaches for the style of navigation I am trying to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand there are lots of errors doing this. But we have alternative options for this you will surely like:

1. jQuery History Plugin :  http://plugins.jquery.com/history/ (Demo: http://4nf.org/)
2. History JS: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/
3. But I would recommend HTML5 `history.pushState` if you are willing to avoid older browser support. (Demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Good luck!!